# How to capture photo while recording video in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Here, I am taking recording video from back camera of device. While taking video how to capture photo and save to photoLibrary.

here is the code i used:

```
 var photoTagImage = Data()
```

Highlighter button used take photo while taking video

```
@IBAction func HightLightButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //        return

    self.selectedtagsArray = NSMutableArray.init()

    if self.recordEventInfo.isDayEvent {
        let clipSecond: Int64 = 30
        let clipName: String = "Hightlight"

        let dict: Dictionary <String, Any> = [
            "clipcapturesecond": Int64(self.totalRecordedSecond),
            "cliptagsecond":     clipSecond,
            "clipname":          clipName,
            "teamname":          "",
            "tagsArray":         self.selectedtagsArray,
            "clipDate":          Date.init()
        ]

        self.videoClipsArray.add(dict)

    } else if self.recordEventInfo.isMatchEvent {
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.delegate =  self

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let clipSecond: Int64 = 30
        let clipName: String = "Hightlight"
        let dict: Dictionary <String, Any> = [
            "clipcapturesecond": Int64(self.totalRecordedSecond),
            "cliptagsecond":     clipSecond,
            "clipname":          clipName,
            "teamname":          "",
            "tagsArray":         self.selectedtagsArray,
            "clipDate":          Date.init(),
            "clipImage":         photoTagImage
        ]

        print("phototagimage: \(photoTagImage)")

        self.matchEventvideoClipsArray.add(dict)
    }
}
```

After taking photo it should save to photo library

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    let imageUniqueName: Int64 = Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)

    let filePath = docDir.appendingPathComponent("\(imageUniqueName).png")

    do {
        if let pngimage = UIImagePNGRepresentation((info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!) {

            photoTagImage = pngimage

            print("photoImage::::::\(photoTagImage)")

            try pngimage.write(to : filePath , options : .atomic)

            /*FETCH DATA:
             public static func fetchData(nameImage : String) -> UIImage{

             let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
             let filePath = docDir.appendingPathComponent(nameImage);

             if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path){

             if let containOfFilePath = UIImage(contentsOfFile : filePath.path){

             return containOfFilePath;

             }

             }

             return UIImage();
             }
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I can able record video but not able to take photo.
I have printed value print("phototagimage: (photoTagImage)") it shows photoImage is 0 bytes.

Here is screenshot of video recording and photo taking [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, and save my screenshot to PhotoLibrary.

```
@IBOutlet weak var shutterButton: UIButton!



@IBAction func HightLightButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
                self.shutterButton.isHidden = true
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), false, 0.0)
                self.view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
                if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

                }
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                self.shutterButton.isHidden = false

            }
```

Comment: is there a difference between capturing the screen like this and taking a photo through the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate methods?

Answer (score 2):

What if you can take screenshot of the view to get image and do something with it.

```
extension UIView {
 func currentViewToImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size)
    self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image

 }
}
```

Or

Get screenshot of window:

```
guard let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layer else { return }
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: layer.frame.size)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
})

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```