# Taking a snapshot of UIImageView instead of main View

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have in my app in my View a Button for taking snapshot with below code

```
open func takeScreenshot(_ shouldSave: Bool = true) -> UIImage? {
    var screenshotImage :UIImage?
    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
    layer.render(in:context)
    screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if let image = screenshotImage, shouldSave {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    }
    return screenshotImage
}
```

But in the same View is UIImageView and I want to take a snapshot of this UIImageView. How should I change the code? When I take a snapshot with this code, it will save only black screen with button for play/pause video and with button for taking snapshot.

Comment: did u check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055910/how-to-capture-photo-while-recording-video-in-ios-swift/50056336#50056336

Comment: thank you, I was looking for wrong title

Answer (score 0):

Instead you using

`let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer`

Just use your imageview Layer

```
let layer = YourImageView.layer
```

Comment: When I tried this, I get only white screen. The video is downloaded from https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4. I can see the video, but when I take a snapshot, it takes only the white screen, which is not in the app.

Comment: What you need to take snapShot to your video , if you have image make sure that imageView have image before you excute previous code

Comment: I am sorry,I am not sure, if I understand. I have a live stream video on my tcp server. From this server I am downloading it into my app using VLCkit and in this app I have UIImageView in which is the video. And I want to take a snapshot of this UIImageView. So you are telling me to do what exactly?

Comment: you need snapshot to Video